# One to many relationship between two assets hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying a test a use case where I have taken two assets: a car and parts. I want to link the car with different instances of parts using a transaction. My model and js files are below :

```
namespace org.sample.test

asset Part identified by partId {
   o String partId
   o String partName
   o String partManufacturer
}

asset Car identified by Vin {
   o String Vin
   --> Part part optional
   o String modelNumber
}

transaction MakeCar{
   o String carid 
   o String carmodel 
   o String[] PartId
}


/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {org.sample.test.MakeCar} tx The sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */
async function makecar(tx) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

   var factory = getFactory();
   var vehicle = factory.newResource('org.sample.test','Car',tx.carid);
   vehicle.modelNumber = tx.carmodel;

   var part = factory.newRelationship('org.sample.test','Part',tx.PartId);
   vehicle.part = part;
   const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.sample.test.Car');
   await assetRegistry.add(vehicle);
  // Update the asset in the asset registry.
   }
```

I also tried first creating the asset using the getfactory then creating relations by traversing partIds one by one using array but then as my Car asset is not created yet its throwing error.

I updated my transaction fucntion :

```
async function makecar(tx) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

   var factory = getFactory();
   var part;
   var vehicle = factory.newResource('org.sample.test','Car',tx.carid);
   vehicle.modelNumber = tx.carmodel;
   var i=0;
   while (i<tx.PartId.length)
   {
     part = factory.newRelationship('org.sample.test','Part',tx.PartId[i]);
     vehicle.part = part;
     i++;
    }
    assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.sample.test.Car');
    await assetRegistry.add(vehicle);
  }
```

Now its giving error : t: Instance org.sample.test.Car#OOOO has property part with type org.sample.test.Part that is not derived from org.sample.test.Part[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is this line:

```
var part = factory.newRelationship('org.sample.test','Part',tx.PartId);
```

it should be [something like]:

```
 var part = factory.newRelationship('org.example.trading','Part',tx.PartId[0]); // 1st element of an array
```

its because you've defined `tx.PartId` as an array of relationships in your transaction definition, so you need to access the relevant element.

At this point, I'm not sure how you want to move forward, but your Car (vehicle) asset has an optional one to one relationship with Part (part Id) which is the optional field in your model. Perhaps it needs to be an array of relationships ? `-> Part[] part optional`  But replacing the line above, will at least have it working, in its present form.  An example of using an array of relationships is shown in the answer in this SO: -> [Creating new participant and adding array of assets by reference to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820526/creating-new-participant-and-adding-array-of-assets-by-reference-to-it/50823033#50823033)  (in particular :`shares` array in the model there)

Comment: yes it should be -> Part[] part optional (typo). Please have a look at my updated transaction function.

Comment: I looked again the example you have mentioned and I pushed all the relationships in a variable one by one and then assigned to vehicle part. It worked , thanks :)